# Insert html in obout editor

Tags: asp.net, obout

I am using obout editor in my application to edit the contents.

I want to place an content Inside the obout editor from the list-box. By using "set_content" function i can fetch the contents for editor, but I want to achieve this with "Inserthtml" function.

The "set_content" function it inserts the content at the end, But i want to insert the content in place of cursor.I googled lot but there is no luck..

In javascript/Jquery iam not able to get the editor id , Is that is the reason for this issues..?

How can i do this..?

Please help me in this...